# MySQL query to get multiple values from 1 table based on multiple columns from other table

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure (let's call this table `teams`):

```
id | player1 | player2 | player3
1  | 13      | 25      | 50
```

And this (let's call this table `players`):

```
id | pts
13 | 5
25 | 10
50 | 12
```

Is there a way to write one query to get the `pts` vlaue for each of the players from a row in table `teams`?

For instance, if I wanted to get the `pts` value for player1, I would do something like:

```
select teams.id,players.pts from teams left join players on teams.player1=players.id
```

I need to do this for all 3 players at once (in reality, there are 18 players, not 3 - but the same principle should work).

I'm aware I can loop through them but that hardly seems like the optimal solution.

Comment: You might consider normalising your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  player1.pts AS player1_pts,
  player2.pts AS player2_pts,
  player3.pts AS player3_pts
FROM
  teams
  LEFT JOIN players AS player1 ON team.player1=player1.id
  LEFT JOIN players AS player2 ON team.player2=player2.id
  LEFT JOIN players AS player3 ON team.player3=player3.id
WHERE
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this solution because it solves this particular issue (even though I see from the other answers that there are better long-term solutions).

Answer (score 3):

I think a better idea would be to have the following structure:

**teams**

```
team_id | name
----------------
1       | Team 1
2       | Team 2
3       | Team 3
```

**players**

```
player_id | pts
---------------
1         | 10
2         | 5
3         | 25
```

**teams_players_xrefs**

```
team_id | player_id
-------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 3
```

And then use the following query:

```
SELECT
  player_id,
  pts
FROM
  teams_players_xrefs
INNER JOIN
  players USING (player_id)
WHERE
  team_id = 1
```

To get the following result:

```
player_id | pts
---------------
1         | 10
2         | 5
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d6e/2).

Comment: Nice answer, we must have been typing the same answer at the same time - although yours has more information so I think I'll delete mine.

Comment: I see what you both mean. However, I can't do that. It's for a rather complex (and live) fantasy sports website, and changing the structure at this point would require weeks of work. This is because there are other things to consider which I didn't bring up in the question, such as player positions, dependencies between players etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could left join the `players` table for each player, this would work but isn't really an ideal solution. Unfortunately due to your table structure is the best you can do.

It would be much better to create a mapping table, mapping teams with players.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE teams
(
  id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );

CREATE TABLE team_players
(
  team_id INT,
  player_id INT
)
```

This would allow you to then query by team_id and return all the players within that team easily.